# How to set the size of the indicator icon in Indicator3?

Tags: java, android, viewpagerindicator

I am used ViewPager2 and CircleIndicator 3 for my image slider but the size of the unselected and selected icons isn't equal.

[image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEI5X.png)

This is my code:

```
<me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator3
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:ci_drawable="@drawable/ic_indicator"
        app:ci_drawable_unselected="@drawable/ic_indicator_unselected"
        app:ci_height="8dp"
        app:ci_width="8dp"
        app:ci_margin="8dp"/>
```

Anyone knows how to set size (width and height) for the indicator icon? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: That is a feature of this library that you are using. If  you  don't need it you can turn if off if that control is available in this or use another dependency